# Getting error when launching Jenkins slave on Ubuntu 14.04 remotely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow

Error in Jenkins ver. 1.640, Ubuntu 14.04. This problem a lot of times in Jenkins, and can't resolve it. I get the following output

```
        [01/22/16 07:35:31] [SSH] Checking java version of java

        [01/22/16 07:35:36] [SSH] java -version returned 1.7.0_65.
        [01/22/16 07:35:36] [SSH] Starting sftp client.

        [01/22/16 07:35:40] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...

        [01/22/16 07:41:10] [SSH] Copied 506,256 bytes.

        Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
        [01/22/16 07:41:12] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/home/tmp" && java  -jar slave.jar

        <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

        Slave.jar version: 2.53.2

        This is a Unix slave

        Evacuated stdout

        Connection terminated
        ERROR: Failed to install restarter
        hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
            at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:297)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
            at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
            at ......remote call to Mbox_19(Native Method)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
            at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
            at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.install(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:52)
            at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.access$000(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:33)
            at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:39)
            at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:36)
            at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
        Caused by: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
            at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
        Caused by: Command close created at
            at hudson.remoting.Command.<init>(Command.java:56)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1074)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1072)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1156)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1138)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1079)
            ... 2 more
        hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
            at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:297)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
            at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
            at ......remote call to Mbox_19(Native Method)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
            at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
            at org.jenkinsci.modules.launchd_slave_installer.SlaveInstallerFactoryImpl.createIfApplicable(SlaveInstallerFactoryImpl.java:30)
            at org.jenkinsci.modules.slave_installer.SlaveInstallerFactory.createIfApplicable(SlaveInstallerFactory.java:29)
            at org.jenkinsci.modules.slave_installer.SlaveInstallerFactory.createFor(SlaveInstallerFactory.java:46)
            at org.jenkinsci.modules.slave_installer.impl.ComputerListenerImpl.onOnline(ComputerListenerImpl.java:30)
            at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:573)
            at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:381)
            at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:945)
            at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$400(SSHLauncher.java:133)
            at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:711)
            at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:696)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
            at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
        Caused by: Command close created at
            at hudson.remoting.Command.<init>(Command.java:56)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1074)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1072)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1156)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1138)
            at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1079)
            ... 2 more
        [01/22/16 07:48:40] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
        [01/22/16 07:48:40] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks related to an existing Jenkins [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14332).

It seems this can be resolved by downgrading to kernel 3.4.x. Another possible fix is disabling TCP scatter-gather on the network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> Tick check-box "Enable security", 
then see "TCP port for JNLP slave agents" and select Random as option.